# Laravel: Mixed Users Database Schema

Tags: database, laravel, database-design

I am working on a database schema for a Laravel project and am unsure of how to design it properly. I have mocked up the majority of the schema, but am unsure of how to make the last leap to properly include users.

[image: Laravel database schema]

There are 8 tables, and the business model is meant to keep track of medical practices, the doctors assigned to them, their patients, the RXs that are written on those patients and what Meds are written in the prescriptions.

Where I come into the issue is that our users table will include our business' staff, representatives, sometimes the distributors of those representatives, and a select few doctors that will want to view their own production. So the users is a mixed bag of people spread across the Distributors, Reps, and Doctors tables with a few of our staff thrown on top of it. Thus far, I have created a 'UserRole' column in the Users table to reflect what the user's capacity is, but that is all.

Can someone assist me with how this should be reflected in the schema, and any thoughts on how to optimize the schema overall if they have any ideas? I am very, very new to both database design and Laravel. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a number of ways to go about this but I followed an approach recently that provided a lot of flexibility for me.

So my simple approach is to keep the `Users` table as a base. With the minimum required user data like `name, username, password, email, phone number, created_at etc` and the `User ID (user_id)` would serve as foreign key to be used anywhere else that actually apply to all users.

From there, when creating a doctor profile, or a distributor etc, you follow the same user structure.

Hope this helps.